# How to expand and add item instantly in tree?

Tags: angularjs

I have a tree of li, and a add button with a modal window to add item to it as parent item or as child item.

When I add new item to `li` as child or as parent item , the tree should expand, but when I add child items to it again , tree collapse instantly.

If I replaced `$modelinstance.close()` by `$modelinstance.dismiss()` tree is working perfectly. But I need refresh to see item added - it is not showing the added item instantly.

Below is the code (`attribute` is a service):

```
Attributes.saveAttribute($scope.attribute, function() {
   toastr.success('Attribute added successfully', 'Success');
   console.log($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id);

      $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();

   var settingtimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if ($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id) {
         angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)).click();
         console.log($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id);
      }
   }, 1000);
}, function(err) {
   $scope.error = err;
});
```

Comment: Can you please make a [plunk](https://plnkr.co)

Comment: try this and see if this works for you.. `modalInstance.result.then(function() {
      $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
   },function() {
      $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
   }   
);`

Comment: i didnt get i idea how to use that... where i have to ust this.... can u copy the code and put this inside that?

Comment: Replace this with your current modalInstance.result.then code

Comment: i tried but didnt worked.... model doesnt even closed...
can u show how to use that inside my code....

Comment: why is that `$scope.modalInstance.close();` at the bottom of the code?

Comment: lets discuss this in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103560/how-to-expand-and-add-item-instantly-in-tree)

Comment: i forgot to coment it out...it dolesnt matter...
 i replaced $scope.modalInstance.dismiss(); with your code....

Comment: i dnt have 20 reputation to chat...

Comment: i made a few changes in the above code.....pls check... dats my original code

Comment: You don't understand ... I can't help you much with such little level of details.. either give me some more code.. or make a minimal thing, I can build upon

Comment: there must be some `modal.result` promise handler in your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454208/angularjs-tree-editing-and-adding-with-model-how-to-implement-correctly

Comment: same questn with more code