# angularjs tree editing and adding with model how to implement correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I have a tree of li, and a add button with a modal window to add item to it as parent item or as child item.

When I add new item to li as child or as parent item , the tree should expand, but when I add child items to it again , tree collapse instantly.

If I replaced $modelinstance.close() by $modelinstance.dismiss() tree is working perfectly. But I need refresh to see item added - it is not showing the added item instantly.

Below is the code (attribute is a service):

```
$scope.saveAttribute = function(form) {
   $scope.submitted = true;
   if (form.$valid) {
      if (!$scope.attributeAction) {
         $scope.createAttributeObject();
      }
      //if edit
      if ($scope.attributeAction && $scope.attributeAction === 'Edit') {
         Attributes
            .editAttribute({
               id: $scope.attribute._id
            }, $scope.attribute, function() {
               toastr.success('Attribute saved successfully', 'Success');
               $scope.modalInstance.close();
            }, function(err) {
               $scope.error = err;
            });
      } else {
         //new attribute
         Attributes
            .saveAttribute($scope.attribute, function() {
               //console.log($scope.modalInstance);
               $scope.modalInstance.close($scope);
               toastr.success('Attribute added successfully', 'Success');
               setTimeout(function() {
                  if ($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id) {
                     //if($scope.modalInstance.close()){
                     console.log($scope.modalInstance.dismiss());
                     angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)).click();
                  }
               }, 1000);
            }, function(err) {
               $scope.error = err;
            });
      }
   }
};
```

Attributes service

```
//service code
angular.module('createWhimsyApp')
   .factory('Attributes', AttributesService);
/**
 * Attribute service
 * @param {Object} $resource Attibute resource
 */
function AttributesService($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/attributes/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
   }, {
      getAllAttributes: {
         isArray: true,
         method: 'GET'
      },
      saveAttribute: {
         method: 'POST'
      },
      editAttribute: {
         method: 'PUT',
         params: {
            id: 'attribute._id'
         }
      },
      deleteAttribute: {
         method: 'DELETE',
         params: {
            id: 'attrObj._id'
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: does edit work good?

Comment: and can you provide the definition of `Attributes.saveAttribute`

Comment: everything work fine... except tree expanding while adding item

Comment: and can you provide the definition of `Attributes.saveAttribute`

Comment: i have added code for my service Attributes

Comment: is there a `modalInstance.result` somewhere in your code?

Comment: try calling.. `Attributes.getAllAttributes();` just before `$scope.modalInstance.close($scope);`

Comment: not working... why you were using that getallattribute ?

Comment: the problem is everything works fine when i using modelinstance.dismiss istead of close...
when i use dismiss i need to reload the page manually to view the added item.... 
so what i want is after adding the item the entire page need to refresh and that click() function should execute again..... 
any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103791/discussion-between-minato-and-vis-prasad).